# Android and Unicode

Tags: text-input

How do I enter a Unicode character in Gboard by entering, say, the Unicode number for that character? Is there a special Unicode keyboard that works in this way?

Today, I wanted to enter a Unicode character found in ncurses, the one for a UL corner (this selection was wrong. But I still wanted to attempt entering the character). Or, perhaps, the lower left. Or the combination of UL and LL characters from ncurses.

In these cases, I need to either draw a character, insert it and have it occupy a cursor place. Or, enter it using the Unicode number for that character.

But there is no way to do these two things.

Comment: The other two ncurses characters, should probably be called BW (best winner), and SW (selfish winner). The UL is the upper loser, and the LL is the lower loser. (? But, actually, the other two characters, I have trouble typing.

Comment: Another possibility, is, BB best block, LB lower block, BS best sky, ... what would lower sky be.

Comment: Sorry, if I have diverged on nomenclature, but, this is relevant. If, we do not, have, the right nomenclature, we cannot program. Someone, will, come up, with something good (a good, framework, for writing certain image characters, in web interfaces, that look like they are a bit PacMan, character, based.

Comment: There are four corner characters in ncurses, a C toolkit for writing text based interfaces, but Android uses Java.

Comment: What, else (is there)?

Comment: Unclear if you searched with "[gboard] unicode" which brings up: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgboard%5D+unicode Some of the answers there provide options. Your comments for me lead to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character as possible nomenclature.